# Sigma algebra -probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Define: $\Omega=${$1,2,...,10$}. I must find : $\sigma (${$1,2,4$},{$3,4,5$},{$2,6$}$)$
I tried to write elements of this collection but there are a lot of them. All paddings and sums. Does anyone have any idea how to make it simplify?

Comment: If you have Mathematica, try this http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Oct/msg00218.html

Comment: The atoms of this Boolean algebra are $\{1\},\ \{2\},\ \{4\},\ \{3,5\},\ \{6\}$. It has thus $32$ elements.

Comment: Only 32? I wrote more than 32

Comment: Ahh.. $64$, sorry, I skipped the atom $\{7,8,9,10\}$. All elements can be expressed as a union of these atoms. Each atom is either present in the union or not, that's how it is $2^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Finite $\sigma$-algebras are just Boolean algebras.
Finite Boolean algebras are determined by its *atoms* (elements $A\ne\emptyset$ such that $B\subseteq A$ implies $B=A$ or $B=\emptyset$):
Every element $X$ can be uniquely written as $X=\bigcup_{A\in H} A$ for a subset $H$ of the atoms.

Now you only have to determine the atoms in the generated $\sigma$- (Boolean) algebra.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$D_1=\{ 1\}$ $D_2=\{2\}$ $D_3=\{3,5\}$ $D_4=\{4\}$ $D_5=\{6\}$ $D_6=\{7,8,9,10\}$

$\sigma (${$1,2,4$},{$3,4,5$},{$2,6$}$)=\sigma \big(\{D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5,D_6 \}\big) $ $\hspace{1cm} 2^6$

$=\bigg\{\phi ,\Omega ,$

$\cup_{i=1}^{6} D_i,$

$\cup_{\substack{i_1,i_2=1 \\ i_1\neq i_2}}^{6} D_{i_1}\cup D_{i_2},$

$\cup_{\substack{i_1,i_2,i_3=1 \\ i_1\neq i_2\neq i_3}}^{6} D_{i_1}\cup D_{i_2} \cup D_{i_3},$

$\cup_{\substack{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4=1 \\ i_1\neq i_2\neq i_3\neq i_4}}^{6} D_{i_1}\cup D_{i_2} \cup D_{i_3}\cup D_{i_4},$

$\cup_{\substack{i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,i_5=1 \\ i_1\neq i_2\neq i_3\neq i_4\neq i_5}}^{6} D_{i_1}\cup D_{i_2} \cup D_{i_3}\cup D_{i_4}\cup D_{i_5}$
$
\bigg\}$